# Where/how is Django ManyToManyField represented in the database?

Tags: python, django

***UPDATE:*** *Just found out that the ManyToManyField is causing the admin interface to crash, when a specific album is selected. I commented them out, commented out all references to it, reran `makemigrations` and `migrate`, and now the admin interface works again...which leaves me even farther away from making this "favorite" column work   :(  See this followup: [Why is Django ManyToManyField causing admin interface to crash? Why is no through table being created?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25435486/why-is-django-manytomanyfield-causing-admin-interface-to-crash-why-is-no-throug)*

---

Background: My goal is to make the "Favorite?" column in this webpage reflect the favorite albums of the currently-logged-in user, where each is either "no" or "yes", and is a clickable link to toggle the choice. (When not logged in, they will all be grey "n/a"-s.)

[image]

Therefore, for each album, there may be exactly *zero or one* "has favorited" entry per user. If the entry exists, they've favorited it. If it doesn't exist, they didn't.

Here is my `Album` model, with the `favorited_by_users` many-to-many column (full `models.py` at the bottom):

```
class Album(models.Model):
    OFFICIALITY = (
        ('J', 'Major studio release'),
        ('I', 'Non-major official release'),
        ('U', 'Unofficial'),
    )
    title = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=500, default="", null=True, blank=True)
    pub_date = models.DateField('release date')
    officiality = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=OFFICIALITY)
    is_concert = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    main_info_url = models.URLField(blank=False)
    thumbnail = models.FileField(upload_to=get_upload_file_name, blank=True, null=True)

    #virtual field to skip over the through table.
    songs = models.ManyToManyField("Song", through="AlbumSong")

    favorited_by_users = models.ManyToManyField(User)

    def __str__(self):
        return  self.title

    class Meta:
        #Default ordering is by release date, ascending.
        ordering = ['pub_date']
```

I originally had this `FavoriteAlbum` model, but since it has no extra information beyond the foreign keys, it was recommended that I eliminate it in favor of the above many-to-many column.

```
class FavoriteSongs(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    song = models.ForeignKey(Song)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('user', 'song',)

    def __str__(self):
        return  "user=" + str(self.user) + ", song=" + str(self.song)
```

What I need to do is a "left join" between album and user, where all albums are selected, and any favorites by the currently-logged-in user are joined to it (`None` if they haven't favorited it). I don't know what to do.

I've also been told about the [`extra()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/querysets/#extra) function to do this join.  The currently-working query in the view's `get_queryset()` is

```
return  super(AlbumList, self).get_queryset().order_by("pub_date")
```

(Full `views.py` below.) My current guess is this:

`return  super(AlbumList, self).get_queryset().order_by("pub_date").extra(select={"is_favorite": "favorited_by_users__id = " + str(request.user.id) })`

But, while this doesn't crash, the value of each `{{ is_favorite }}` in the template is *nothing* (the empty string). This makes sense since there's nothing in the database yet, but what now? I have no idea if this is the correct Django query.

I want to add an item in the database to test this, with a manual SQL statement in postgres (not via a Django command yet), but how and where do I do this?

I've successfully run `makemigrations` and then `migrate` with this new m2m column (and without the `FavoriteSongs` model), but I see nothing in the database that represents the is-favorite value. There's no extra column in `billyjoel_album`, and no through table akin to `billyjoel_favoritealbum`. So where/how is this data stored in the database?

(Any other advice regarding this extra "favorite" column would be appreciated as well!)

Thanks.

---

models.py

```
from  django.db import models
from  django.contrib.auth.models import User
from  time import time

def get_upload_file_name(instance, filename):
    return  "uploaded_files/%s_%s" % (str(time()).replace(".", "_"), filename)

class Album(models.Model):
    OFFICIALITY = (
        ('J', 'Major studio release'),
        ('I', 'Non-major official release'),
        ('U', 'Unofficial'),
    )
    title = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=500, default="", null=True, blank=True)
    pub_date = models.DateField('release date')
    officiality = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=OFFICIALITY)
    is_concert = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    main_info_url = models.URLField(blank=False)
    thumbnail = models.FileField(upload_to=get_upload_file_name, blank=True, null=True)

    #virtual field to skip over the through table.
    songs = models.ManyToManyField("Song", through="AlbumSong")

    favorited_by_users = models.ManyToManyField(User)

    def __str__(self):
        return  self.title

    class Meta:
        #Default ordering is by release date, ascending.
        ordering = ['pub_date']


class Song(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=500, default="", null=True, blank=True)
    length_seconds = models.IntegerField()
    lyrics_url = models.URLField(default="", blank=True, null=True)
    albums = models.ManyToManyField("Album", through="AlbumSong")

    favorited_by_users = models.ManyToManyField(User)

    def get_length_desc_from_seconds(self):
        if(self.length_seconds == -1):
            return  "-1"
        m, s = divmod(self.length_seconds, 60)
        h, m = divmod(m, 60)
        if(h):
            return  "%d:%02d:%02d" % (h, m, s)
        else:
            return  "%d:%02d" % (m, s)

    def __str__(self):
        return  self.name

class AlbumSong(models.Model):
    song = models.ForeignKey(Song)
    album = models.ForeignKey(Album)
    sequence_num = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('album', 'sequence_num',)
        unique_together = ('album', 'song',)

    def __str__(self):
        return  str(self.album) + ": " + str(self.sequence_num) + ": " + str(self.song)
```

views.py

```
from  .models import Album, Song, AlbumSong
from  datetime import datetime, timedelta
from  django.core.context_processors import csrf
from  django.shortcuts import render, render_to_response
from  django.views.generic import DetailView, ListView
from  enum import Enum

def get_str_with_appended(string, between_if_str_non_empty, new_value):
    if(len(string) == 0):
        return  new_value
    else:
        return  string + between_if_str_non_empty + new_value

class PrependQuestionMark(Enum):
    YES, NO = range(2)

def get_url_param_string_from_params(prepend_question_mark=PrependQuestionMark.YES, **kwargs_all_params):
    param_list = ""
    for  key in iter(kwargs_all_params):
        value = kwargs_all_params[key]
        if(value is not None):
            param_list = get_str_with_appended(param_list, '&', str(key) + "=" + str(value))

    if(len(param_list) == 0):
        return  param_list;

    if(prepend_question_mark == PrependQuestionMark.YES):
        return  "?" + param_list
    else:
        return  param_list

class AlbumList(ListView):
    model = Album
    context_object_name = "albums"

    #Derived from irc/#dango/tbaxter...START
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
                                             #default to asc
        self.sort_order = request.GET.get("sort_order", None)
        self.sort_item = request.GET.get("sort_item", None)
        self.csrf_token = csrf(request)["csrf_token"]
        self.logged_in_user = request.user

        #self.csrf_token = request.GET.get("csrf_token", None)
        return super(AlbumList, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get_queryset(self):
        #Item zero in both is the default
        #should be static global
        asc_desc_list = ["asc", "dsc"]
        sort_by_types = ["pub_date", "title"]

        if(self.sort_order is None  and  self.sort_item is None):
            #Use default ordering
            return  super(AlbumList, self).get_queryset()

        #Custom ordering requested

        sort_order = self.sort_order
        sort_item = self.sort_item

        if(sort_order is None  or
                sort_order not in asc_desc_list):
            sort_order = asc_desc_list[0]
        if(sort_item is None  or
                sort_item not in sort_by_types):
            sort_item = sort_by_types[0]

        order_minus = ""  if  sort_order == "asc"  else "-"

        return  super(AlbumList, self).get_queryset().order_by(order_minus + sort_item).extra(select={"is_favorite": "favorited_by_users__id = " + str(self.logged_in_user.id) })

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(AlbumList, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

        context["sort_order"] = self.sort_order
        context["sort_item"] = self.sort_item

        context["url_params"] = get_url_param_string_from_params(
            sort_item=self.sort_item,
            sort_order=self.sort_order,
            csrf_token=self.csrf_token)

        return  context


class AlbumDetail(DetailView):
    model = Album
    context_object_name = "album"

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
                                             #default to asc
        self.sort_order = request.GET.get("sort_order", None)
        self.sort_item = request.GET.get("sort_item", None)
        self.csrf_token = csrf(request)["csrf_token"]

        return super(AlbumDetail, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        #Call the base implementation first to get a context
        context = super(AlbumDetail, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

        #Add in the required extra info: album_songs, ordered by
        #sequence_num

        #select_related is to query the database for all songs at once, here
        #in the view, to prevent the template from pin-pricking the database
        #in each for loop iteration. For large datasets, this is critical.
        context['album_songs'] = kwargs["object"].albumsong_set.order_by('sequence_num').select_related("song")

        context["url_params"] = get_url_param_string_from_params(
            sort_item=self.sort_item,
            sort_order=self.sort_order,
            csrf_token=self.csrf_token)

        return  context
```

album_list.html

```
 {% extends "base.html" %}
 {% load bj_filters %}
 {% block title %}Billy Joel Album Browser{% endblock %}

 {% block sidebar %}
 <UL>
  <LI><a href="{% url 'album_list' %}{{ url_params }}">All albums</A></LI>
  <LI><a href="/admin/">Admin</A></LI>
 </UL>
 {% endblock %}

 {% block content %}

 <TABLE ALIGN="center" WIDTH="100%" BORDER="1" CELLSPACING="0" CELLPADDING="4" BGCOLOR="#EEEEEE"><TR ALIGN="center" VALIGN="middle">
 {% if  user.is_authenticated %}
  <TD>My profile (<a href="{% url 'accounts_logout' %}">Logout</A>)</TD>
 {% else %}
  <TD><a href="{% url 'accounts_login' %}">Login</A> to view your favorites</TD>
 {% endif %}
 </TR></TABLE>

 <H1>Billy Joel Album Browser</H1>

 <!--
 <P>url_params={{ url_params }}</P>
  -->

 {% if  albums.count > 0 %}
  <P>Officiality: <IMG SRC="/static/images/major.jpg" height="20"/>=Major studio release, <IMG SRC="/static/images/minor.jpg" height="20"/>=Official release, <IMG SRC="/static/images/unofficial.jpg" height="20"/>=Unofficial</P>
  <TABLE ALIGN="center" WIDTH="100%" BORDER="1" CELLSPACING="0" CELLPADDING="4" BGCOLOR="#EEEEEE"><TR ALIGN="center" VALIGN="middle">
     <TD><B><U><a href="{% url 'album_list' %}?sort_item=title&sort_order=
        {% if  sort_item == 'pub_date' %}asc{% else %}
           {{ sort_order|multival_to_str:'asc,dsc->dsc,asc,dsc' }}
        {% endif %}
     &csrf_token={{ csrf_token }}">Title</A></U></B><BR><I><FONT SIZE="-1">(click a title to view its song list)</FONT></I></TD>
     <TD><B><U><a href="{% url 'album_list' %}?sort_item=pub_date&sort_order=
        {% if  sort_item == 'title' %}asc{% else %}
           {{ sort_order|multival_to_str:'asc,dsc->dsc,asc,dsc' }}
        {% endif %}
     &csrf_token={{ csrf_token }}">Released</A></U></B></TD>
     <TD>Officiality</TD>
     <TD>Concert</TD>
     <TD>Wiki</TD>
     <TD>Favorite?</TD>
  {% for  album in albums %} <!-- No colon after "albums" -->
  </TR><TR>
     <TD VALIGN="top">
        {% if  album.thumbnail %}
           <img src="/static/{{ album.thumbnail }}" width="25"/>
        {% else %}
           <img src="/static/images/white_block.jpg" width="25"/>
        {% endif %}
        &nbsp; <a href="/albums/get/{{ album.id }}{{ url_params }}">{{ album.title }}</a>
        {% if  album.description %}
           <BR/><FONT SIZE="-1"><I>{{ album.description|truncatewords:10 }}</I></FONT>
        {% endif %}
     <TD>{{ album.pub_date|date:"m/y" }}</TD>
     <TD><IMG SRC="/static/images/{{ album.officiality|multival_to_str:"J,I,U->major,minor,unofficial,broken_image"}}.jpg" height="20"/></TD>
     <TD>{{ album.is_concert|yesno:"Yes,No" }}</TD>
     <TD><A HREF="{{ album.main_info_url }}">Wiki</A></TD>
     <TD><I>n/a {{ is_favorite }}</I></TD>
  {% endfor %}
  </TR></TABLE>
 {% else %}
  <P><I>There are no albums in the database.</I></P>
 {% endif %}

 {% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The many-to-many field is represented in the database in *exactly* the same way as your original FavouriteSongs model - as a linking table with ForeignKeys to both Song and User. The only benefit of getting rid of FavouriteSongs is that you're now using an automatically-defined through table, rather than a manual one.

I don't understand your example query, since you don't say what model you are actually calling it on, or what `self.logged_in_user` is. However, you can't use `extra` like this: you are trying to put Django query syntax there, complete with double-underscore names to traverse relationships, but `extra` is passed directly to the SQL, and that doesn't know anything about that syntax.

I would not attempt to do this in one query. Instead I would do two queries, one to get all the albums and one to get the user's favourites. `get_queryset` would just return the full album list, and then you can use `get_context_data` to get an additional set of objects representing the IDs of the favourites:

```
favorites = self.logged_in_user.album_set.all().values_list('id', flat=True)
context['favorites'] = set(favorites)
```

The values_list just gets the IDs of the albums only, since that's all we need, and we then put them into a set to make lookups quicker.

Now, in the template, you can just do:

```
{% for album in albums %}
    ...
    <td>{% if album.id in favorites %}Yes{% else %}No{% endif %}</td>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 8):

M2M relationships are brand-new tables created. They get an unique name, and have two foreign keys. A composite key is created so the direct and the related model combinations are unique.

When you do:

```
class Topping(models.Model):
    name = ...

class Pizza(models.Model):
    name = ...
    toppings = models.ManyToManyField(Topping, related_name="pizzas")
    #not including a related_name will generate a "pizza_set" related name.
```

A new table appears describing the relationship, with an internal name. This table has a pizza_id and a topping_id foreign key, and a composite unique key including both fields. You cannot, and should not, predict the name of such table.

On the other side, if you want to access the relationship and, possible, declare more fields, you can:

```
class Topping(models.Model):
    name = ...

class Pizza(models.Model):
    name = ...
    toppings = models.ManyToManyField(Topping, related_name="pizzas", through="PizzaAndTopping")
    #not including a related_name will generate a "pizza_set" related name.

class PizzaAndTopping(models.Model):
    more_data = models.TextField()
    pizza = models.ForeignKey(Pizza, null=False)
    topping = models.ForeignKey(Topping, null=False)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('pizza','topping'),)
```

Notice how I added a `through` parameter. Now you have control of the middle-table **BUT you cannot add or delete models from the relationship**. This means, with this approach you cannot:

```
Pizza.objects.get(pk=1).toppings.append(Topping.objects.get(pk=2))
```

Nor you can remove, nor you can do these operations in the Topping side of the life.

If you want to add or delete toppin-pizza relationships, you **must** do it directly in the PizzaAndTopping relationship.

If you want to know whether the current user has marked any song as their favorite, you should **prefetch** the relationship. In Django 1.7, you can prefetch a M2M related field using a custom filter: you can fetch all the albums, and only a query getting the current user, using a `Prefetch` object. See the official docs about prefetching [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related).

Antoher solution would involve:

- fetching the current user's favorite albums list: `ulist = user.album_set.all()`
- fetching the current page of alboms: `_list = Album.objects.all()[0:20]`
- fetch values of user albums: `ulist = ulist.values_list('id', flat=True)`

  ```
  [1, 2, 4, 5, 10, ...] #you'll get a list of ids
  ```
- when iterating over each album in the page, you test `currentAlbum.id in ulist` and print a different message (either yes or no).